# Can I synchronize reads of control variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop, synchronized

The following code will work, but I slightly resent having to write the isRunning() method:

```
class Test {
    private boolean running;
    public void startX() {
        synchronized(this) {
            running = true
        }
        while (isRunning()) {
            //do something
        }
    }
    public synchronized void stopX() {
        running = false;
    }
    private synchronized boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}
```

Can I synchronize reads of the `running` variable in the `while (running){}` in some other way, or do I have to write the isRunning() method? The same question applies to other control variables as well, eg

```
for (;running;) {}
```

or

```
if (running) {}
```

In all of these cases it seems as though you're forced into writing a pointless method to get the synchronization correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just make `running` `volatile`.

Answer (score 3):

if you are only resetting the value of `running` once to designate to stop, you might be able to use the `volatile` keyword.

However, if you need to start and stop many times, this won't work.  This is because volatile fields "may miss an update"

Here's a link to explanation of when `volatile` works in cases like this [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_typical_use.shtml)

here's the code sample from that link incase it goes dead:

```
public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
   private volatile boolean pleaseStop;

   public void run() {
     while (!pleaseStop) {
       // do some stuff...
     }
   }

  public void tellMeToStop() {
     pleaseStop = true;
   }
  }
```

If you need to start and stop many times, then you need to either use one of the Java 5 concurrent lock objects or explicit synchronization

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot guarantee that only a single thread will write to this value, so it has to be synchronized AFAIK

Comment: @user1675642 `volatile` guarantees visibility among different threads, so for this particular case that poses no trouble. And given that writes to `pleaseStop` during execution will always be to true, there is no chance of update misses.

Comment: @E_net4 the `pleaseStop` was from the code example blog I linked to.  The OP might set the flag back if their `startX()` is called again.

Comment: @dkatzel Then that would be a different use case from the one in this question, don't you think? Besides, I was only replying to OP's comment on not guaranteeing writes from a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the running field volatile. Making the field volatile puts the JVM on notice that it should make changes to that field visible to other threads.
The "miss an update" caveat is for cases where you want to read a value and update based on that value, which doesn't seem applicable here.
Multiple threads can write to this field, if all they're doing is setting a boolean flag then this won't be a problem.

Alternatively, if you are trying to cancel a thread, there's already an equivalent flag provided on Thread for this (and the visibility issue is taken care of). You can call interrupt on a thread, the code in the Runnable can query `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`  in order to tell whether it's been interrupted. This is preferable over using your own flag because the interruption will cause the thread to wake up if it is waiting or sleeping. With your own flag you have to wait until control reaches a place where the flag can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

just to add up to other people's answer that suggested `volatile` .
Alternatively you could create a class for the checks.
I have made the variable to be `static`, so all threads will be pointing to same object.

```
class Runner{

 boolean static running=true;

 public static synchronized boolean getRunning(){
     return running;
 }

 public static synchronized boolean setRunning(boolean r){
     running=r;
 }
}
```

**NOTE:**

if you don't require the global variable, then remove the `static`

Comment: I could never approve global monitor synchronization over using a volative field when I can.

Comment: @E_net4 its a matter of opinion mate. I have a program with over 1000 threads running with same behaviour. so far nothing catastrophic happend.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that it's not a scalable solution. Making it static means you cannot even make multiple instances of it.

Comment: @E_net4 **running** does not necessarily have to be static, it all depends on the scenario.

Comment: That argument is fair. But right now your solution is an implementation of an [atomic boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), which is already in the standard library and might be optimized for performance.